# Custom attributes missing in the getUserAttributes response - AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

```
const userData = { Username: username, Pool: userPool };
const cognitoUser = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            alert(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log(result)
                        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            console.log('attribute ' + result[i].getName() + ' has value ' + result[i].getValue());
                        }
                    });
```

I have a custom field userType. I have set the read, write permission for the custom attribute. But in the response of getUserAttributes i am getting only standard attributes(sub, email_verified, email). How can i retrieve both the standard and custom attributes?

This is my response

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else to you need me to answer before accepting the answer?

Answer (score 23):

First of all, you need to make sure the App client has permissions to read the attribute(s).

Go to AWS Cognito, select the User Pool, then General Settings > App clients and select the App Client, then click "Set attribute read and write permissions"

You should see the following [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xAVm.png) (notice I have "custom:premium" attribute created and permission to read set)

Then in order to see the custom attributes in cognitoUser.getUserAttributes() results you need to set some value to it, this can be done for example via AWS CLI with the following command:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
--user-pool-id userPoolId \
--username userName \
--user-attributes Name=custom:premium,Value=1
```

In the example above I'm setting "**custom:premium**" attribute to value 1 (obviously you need to replace **userPoolId** and **userName** with correct values.

- **userPoolId** can be found in AWS Cognito (for example: eu-central-1_896ERRASw)
- **userName** is username of the user you are currently logged in with in your app (and invoking cognitoUser.getUserAttributes())

  [And here is the result of the function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHE1f.jpg) after properly setting permission and value of the custom attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, read permission is what was missing. After checking 'readable' I started to receive custom attributes

Comment: Tom's answer is correct, but not all that useful.  Not his fault but it is a hack.  If you want the field available in the user object there should be no need to enter data into the value with the CLI.  App users should be able to enter the data in an app GUI like we've built real apps for decades.

Comment: @Preston the answer is actually about why the attribute is not appearing in the response, not how to set the data in the attribute. Data are usually set via a function call by the logged in user (as you suggested an UI), however in order to make the answer complete and show working example, I have chosen CLI to allow everyone to quickly replicate the example above and get it working in no time.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, that wasn't clear to me from your post.  +1